# Solve $ax - a^2 = bx - b^2$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

### Method 1

Solve for x
$$ax - a^2 = bx - b^2$$

Collect all terms with x on one side of the equation
$$ax - bx = a^2 -b^2$$

Factor both sides of the equation
$$(a -b)x = (a+b)(a - b)$$

Divide both sides of the equation by the coefficient of $x$  (which is $a-b$)

$$x = a + b$$     (where $a \neq b$ since this would mean dividing by $0$)

### Method 2

Solve for $x$
$$ax - a^2= bx - b^2$$

Bring all the terms to one side of the equation
$$ax - a^2 -bx + b^2 = 0$$

Rearrange
$$ax - bx -(a^2-b^2)=0$$

Factor
$$(a - b)x - (a + b)(a - b) = 0$$

$$(a - b)( x - (a + b)) = 0$$

which is a true statement if $$a-b=0$$ $$a = b$$ or $$x-(a+b)=0$$ $$x = a + b$$

My question is I don't understand how this second method is consistent with the first in terms of the restriction on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: The first method assumes $a\ne b$ and solves for $x$ in terms of them. The second method does not assume $a\ne b$, with solutions split into cases - it is simply more general than the first in that it handles more cases. These are consistent because when $a\ne b$ they give the same answer and do not contradict each other (when $a=b$ the first method doesn't apply so does not contradict anything the second method says).

Comment: @skullpatrol Arjang changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed consistent solutions:

- note: if $a = b$, you have $0 = 0$ (just put $a = b$ and substitute into the original equation).
- Note, in the first method, you acknowledged that you ***could not*** have $a = b$ and validly divide by $(a - b).$ You just forgot to check what happens when $a = b$.

When $a = b$, we have that ***any*** $x$ will solve the equation. That is, $a = b \implies x \in \mathbb R$. That doesn't tell you much! $a = b$ is not itself a solution to $x$.

Comment: Here, though we are sort of treating $x$ as the variable, and $a, b$ as constants. So although we exclude $a - b = 0$ because we cannot divide by zero, we have to consider what happens in terms of $x$ when $a = b$. As it turns out, in both methods, when we consider what happens when $a = b$, we have that there are infinitely many values of $x$ that satisfy the equation when $a = b$. So $a = b$ is not really a solution to $x$ in the second method...it's just that $a = b$ satisfies the equation, regardless of the value of $x$.

Comment: To put it briefly, both methods tell us that the only **unique** solution for $x$ is determined by $x = a+b$. When $a = b$, we know nothing more about $x$ than before we began trying to solve for it: namely, that it is assumed to be some real number.

Comment: Yes, you can look at it that way! That would be a good way to summarize what *seems to be* (but really isn't) discrepancy in results... Alternatively, there are problems when $a = b$, using either method, so we *disallow* the case $a = b$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. By the first method, we do get the true statement $a = b$. Let me explain: In the first method, it is **not** correct to say that, with respect to the original equation, that $a$ cannot equal $b$. Before deividing by $a - b$, we have to consider *what happens when $a$ **does equal** $b$? So, we check that out, using the original equation, and if we do that, by substituting b with $a$, we get the true equation $ax - a^2 = ax - a^2 \implies 0 = 0$. So a = b results in **one** true statement. Then we see what happens when $a\neq b$, and we divide by $a - b$...getting $x = a+b$

Comment: That's what I meant in my answer when I said in your first method, you *forgot* to check what happens when $a = b$. You are right that we cannot divide the equation by zero. But that doesn't mean a cannot equal b. In the case $a = b$, we simply don't divide...we check that out by substituting one for the other, because in that case, $a = b$. When we've checked that out, **then** we proceed to solve for all cases $a \neq b$, and since in all *those* cases, $a\neq b$, we **can** divide by $(a - b)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a=b$, the left side of the equation $(a-b)(x - (a+b)) = 0$ is always equal to the right side, so $x$ can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

In the first method you come to the equation

$$(a-b)x=(a+b)(a-b)$$

In the second method, you come to the equation

$$(a-b)(x-(a+b))=0$$

which is just the first equation rearranged and factored.  If we divide the first equation by $(a-b)$ without factoring, we still collect the solution $a=b$, because notice that it does solve the first equation.  However, we continue on assuming $a\ne b$ to discover the other solution.

The method is the same with the second equation.  We first collect the solution $a=b$, and then we assume $a\ne b$ to see if there are other solutions.  By the zero product property, it follows that we must have $x=a+b$.